# React Prop Types - On false prop type, reset to default?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

Say I am using a button in React:

```
<Button appearance="primary"> Primary </Button>
```

In my Button Class I have the following code:

```
StyledButton.defaultProps = {
  appearance: 'primary'
};

StyledButton.propTypes = {
  appearance: propTypes.oneOf(['primary', 'secondary']),
};
```

This works fine. If I don't specify any prop, it will default to `primary`. But if I write:

```
<Button appearance="blabla"> Primary </Button>
```

...I would like my code to notice that this is **not** a valid prop type (not either `primary` or `secondary`) and so automatically set it back to the default.

- Is this possible? Or wouldn't you recommend doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach 1

If you want to show an alternate message to user, that invalid prop is used. In HTML

```
const StyledButton = ({ appearance }) => {
   const isValid = ['primary', 'secondary'].includes(appearance);

   if (!isValid) {
     return <p>Invalid prop appearance can only be primary or secondary<p>
   }
   return <Button appearance={appearance}> Primary </Button>
}
```

Approach 2

If you want to throw an error (in console);

```
const StyledButton = ({ appearance }) => {
   const isValid = ['primary', 'secondary'].includes(appearance);

   if (!isValid) {
     throw new Error("Invalid propType appearance, can only be primary or secondary")
   }
   return <Button appearance={appearance}> Primary </Button>
}
```

Comment: Approach 2 is what happens anyway; providing an invalid proptype causes a console warning by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below,

```
    const StyledButton = ({appearance}) => {
       const appearanceUpdate = ['primary', 'secondary'].includes(appearance) ? appearance : "primary"
       return <Button appearance={appearanceUpdate}> Primary </Button>
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is a use case for PropTypes should rather be done in the component itself.
I would do it something like this:

```
const options = ['primary', 'secondary'];
const defaultOption = options[0];

const StyledButton = ({ appearance }) => {
  if (!options.includes(appearance)) appearance = defaultOption;
  // ... actual implementation
}

StyledButton.defaultProps = {
  appearance: defaultOption,
}
StyledButton.propTypes = {
  appearance: PropTypes.oneOf(options)
}
```